# Django Serializer access json data from post (string indices must be integers)

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm trying to create Serializer for a register post request's validation
The json that send to the API with the POST request:

```
{
    "username": "dat@icts.vn",
    "password": "123456",
    "confirm_password": "123456"
}
```

My serializer for validation:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def validate_username(self, username):
        existing_email = User.objects.filter(email=username).first()
        if existing_email:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Email already registered")

        return username
    def validate_confirm_password(self, data):
        if data['password']:
            if data['confirm_password'] != data['password']:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Confirm password not match password")

            return data['confirm_password']
```

My view register function:

```
@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def register(request):
    received_json_data=json.loads(request.body)
    valid_ser = RegisterSerializer(data=received_json_data)
    if valid_ser.is_valid():
        post_username = received_json_data["username"]
        post_password = received_json_data["password"] 
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=post_username,password=post_password)
        user.save()
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

        content = {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        }

        return JsonResponse(content)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'code':'400','errors':valid_ser.errors}, status=400)
```

When i send the POST request i get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
web_1       |     response = get_response(request)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
web_1       |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
web_1       |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
web_1       |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
web_1       |     return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
web_1       |   File "/app/api/views.py", line 84, in register
web_1       |     if valid_ser.is_valid():
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 235, in is_valid
web_1       |     self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 430, in run_validation
web_1       |     value = self.to_internal_value(data)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 489, in to_internal_value
web_1       |     validated_value = validate_method(validated_value)
web_1       |   File "/app/api/views.py", line 49, in validate_confirm_password
web_1       |     if data['password']:
web_1       | TypeError: string indices must be integers
web_1       | [05/Sep/2019 04:59:33] "POST /api/register HTTP/1.1" 500 99431
```

It seems like i can't access the json data vaule with the key in Serializer, i'm kinda stuck on this one any help would be appreciate

Comment: Where are you calling `validate_confirm_password`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rename function `validate_confirm_password` to `validate`.

As explained in a previous response, `validate_{field_name}`  is used as [field validation level](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) and will recieve/return the actual field's value, not the current data.

Instead, what your want to do is using `validate`(eg [Object validation level](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)).

In your case, that'll give:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def validate_username(self, username):
        existing_email = User.objects.filter(email=username).first()
        if existing_email:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Email already registered")

        return username

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password']:
            if data['confirm_password'] != data['password']:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Confirm password not match password")

        return data
```

Comment: i also have to change ValidationError or else it will show the error field belong to non_field_error which is not the correct response . ValidationError({'confirm_password': ['Confirm password not match password']})

Answer (score 3):

As [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) says:

We have two-level validation for initial data:

[Field-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation):

> You can specify custom field-level validation by adding .`validate_<field_name>` methods to your Serializer subclass. These are similar to the .`clean_<field_name>`methods on Django forms.

**Example:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = serializers.CharField()

    def validate_title(self, value):
        """
        Check that the blog post is about Django.
        """
        if 'django' not in value.lower():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Blog post is not about Django")
        return value
```

> **Note:** If your `<field_name>` is declared on your serializer with the parameter `required=False` then this validation step will not take place if the field is not included.

[Object-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation):

> To do any other validation that requires access to multiple fields, add a method called `.validate()` to your Serializer subclass. This method takes a single argument, which is a dictionary of field values. It should raise serializers.ValidationError if necessary, or just return the validated values.

**Example:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class EventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    start = serializers.DateTimeField()
    finish = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        Check that start is before finish.
        """
        if data['start'] > data['finish']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("finish must occur after start")
        return data
```

So you should validate `confirm_password` in `validate(data)` method, that you can access the data like this:

```
def validate(data):

    confirm_password = data.get('confirm_password', None)
    password = data.get('password', None)

    # don't forget to return validated data
    return data
```

Answer (score 2):

It's similar to `validate_username(self, username)` method, `data` param in `validate_confirm_password(self, data)` is actually the password value, which is a string.

Ref [serializer field level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation i didn't know about it until now

Answer (score 0):

In `validate_fieldname(self,  fieldvalue)` you get actual value for that field you are validating.

As you have used the username value direct to filter the existing records in  your `validate_username` method,

But in `validate_confirm_password` method you are trying to validate the password, which is not right way

To validate on complete request you can use `validate` method

```
def validate(self, data):
    username = data["username"]
    password = data["password"]
    confirm_password = data["confirm_password"]
    # your validation  logic
```